# Javascript ternary operator -- what is the condition?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I read a handful of SOF posts on ternary operators but I'm still confused with this example:

```
var str = "I want to count";
var counts = {};
var ch, index, len, count;

for (index = 0; index < str.length; ++index) {
    ch = str.charAt(index); 
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1; // TERNARY
}
```

I know the syntax is
condition ? expression1 : expression2

But I am trying to practice and break up the ternary into an if-else.

I don't know what the condition is supposed to be

counts[ch] = count // this isn't a condition, it's assigning a value...

Comment: `count ? count + 1 : 1` - *"I know the syntax is condition ? expression1 : expression2"* - So then the condition is `count` ?  The assignment happens with the *result* of the expression, it isn't part of the expression.

Comment: So you're looking for the equivalent if/then/else for your ternary?

Comment: `if (count) counts[ch] = count + 1; else counts[ch] = 1;` is the equivalent if else. Is that where your confusion lies?

Comment: If you have something like `counts[ch] = count + 1` and you say "I understand, that the addition consist of two operats `a + b`", you wouldn't assume that `a` in that case is `counts[ch] = count`, but only `count`, so why do you think that the condition is `counts[ch] = count` and not just `count`?

Comment: `count` isn't `false` as in 0, `null`, `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary

```
counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
```

The condition in this expression is not `counts[ch] = count` but just `count` and is equivalent to

```
if (count){
    counts[ch] = count + 1;
}
else {
    counts[ch] = 1;
}
```

The right hand side of an assignment expression is always evaluated first and the `counts[ch]` is assigned the result of `count ? count + 1 ? 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating the ternary with the assignment expression.

The code

```
counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
```

can also be written as

```
counts[ch] = (count ? count + 1 : 1);
// but not (counts[ch] = count) ? count + 1 : 1
// that does something entirely different
```

And then, writing the matching if/else becomes pretty clear

```
if (count) {
   counts[ch] = count + 1;
} else {
   counts[ch] = 1;
}
```